# Matching any characters that's not a plus sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to use regex to match any characters that's not a '+' in between the words 'begin', and 'end' but it's not matching for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
$content = "begin+text1+end begin text2 end";
$regex = "~begin(^\++?)end~";
preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( begin text2 end ) [1] => Array ( text2 ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the anchor `^` within a character class to create a negated character class:

```
"~begin([^+]+)end~"
```

Comment: So, when you want to say not, so and so, you always have to use the [] brackets?

Comment: @frosty Not always, you can also use a negative look around for that aim.But not in this case.

Comment: Yes, but this works just for groups. Negative assertions for whole words are a little bit more difficult

Comment: @AvinashRaj I see there is no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your pattern slightly you should get the expected result:

```
(?=[^\s\d]+)begin([^+\n]+)end
```

This pattern uses a positive lookahead - asserting that space or digit will be inversely matched before the word `begin`. The capture group then grabs anything between that and `end` which doesn't contain a `+` or line break `\n`.

**Result**:

```
Array ([0] => begin text2 end)[1] => Array([0] =>  text2))
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/qS6iL1/2